# mongo.h file not found on yosemite

Tags: c, mongodb, osx-yosemite, mongo-c-driver

I was installed the MongoDB C driver on my Mac OSX Yosemite.

Using

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
make test
```

Everything is okay but when I try to compile C code with Xcode or GCC on terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mongo.h"

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

It notices me that 
`test.c:3:10: fatal error: 'mongo.h' file not found`

then, I'm not see mongo.h file or any in /usr/include, and yes I already install MongoDB.

Am I missed something?